# Laravel Change background from database information

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a Crud application. i have a database table called 'tag' in here is a column called 'color'

In my index.blade.php (for the crud) i want my table row to be the color i put in my database, by string.

Data example;

```
[id = '1', name = 'dutch', color = 'red']
```

code i currently have in my blade file:

```
  @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$tag->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$tag->name}} </td>
            <td style="background:{{$tag['color']}} ;">{{$tag->color}} </td>
```

Comment: So what is your question? What is happening? Are you getting some kind of error? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73828886/edit) with more details and an actual question, please and thank you.

Comment: will do. i just get an error and it does not work

Comment: What error, and what does *"does not work"* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Add background-color, It would be Much better if you can save Color codes instead of strings in DB.

```
            <td style="background-color:{{$tag['color']}} ;">{{$tag->color}</td>
```

Comment: *"It would be Much better if you can save Color codes instead of strings"* - Yes, but `'red'` is a perfectly valid color in CSS, `background-color: red;` and `background-color: #ff0000` are equivalent.

Comment: that's right but i believe you can have around 16 colours by using string, for more colors you will require HEX codes

Comment: Oh there are _a lot_ more than 16 color strings available in CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp  *"All modern browsers support the following 140 color names [...]"*. You are correct though; Hex Codes support something like 16 million